# Magento 2 REST API Get All Product

Tags: rest, api, product, magento2

I am trying to get all products from Magento 2 using REST api, is there any resource that can do the GET for all products ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `catalogProductRepositoryV1 -> [GET] /V1/products`

Comment: This doesn't work to get *all* products:  /V1/products requires some criterion to filter on.

Answer (score 15):

For all products: `/V1/products?searchCriteria[pagesize]`

For 20 products: `/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=20`

Comment: /V1/products?searchCriteria returns a 500 error for me

Comment: @TaylorAustin check your web server error log.

Comment: @Nahid That is most probably because the response is too big. Try with the pageSize to see if you are able to get products in general

Answer (score 7):

**Magento 2 Provides Swagger Module and it listed all API resources:**

Magento2 RESTful API is based on swagger specification and uses swagger ui tool to generate and visualize API documentation so it can be easily understood and used.

Magento2 provides Magento_Swagger module to list, visualise and at the same time test the API resources.

If you have installed Magento2 on your server then you can easily access all the API resources listed on your website by just hitting this URL:

- example: http://www.your_url.com/swagger

All the API resources will be listed. you can click on each resource to check all the details about the api, resource url, method, params and even you can execute the API call on the same place and check the response.